# Merging unallocated space into existing partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora-15

I need some help with merging free `3.7GB unallocated` space with my existing `ext4 partition`. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Keeping the data on the existing ext4 partition is of utmost importance, I do not wish to lose or corrupt any of the data.

Is this possible with my existing setup?

[image: Filesystem description in Gparted]

---

Additional information:

I've got

- Fedora15 on sda5 (ext4)
- windows on sda3
- Debian6 on sda5 (ext3) whose grub is currently being used.

Answer (score 0):

What unalocated space? that 3.7GB? or you want to resize the NTFS partition?

either way, you can move the partitions until you put the free space in the end... it will take ages but it does work (as always when playing with partitions, have updated backups, just in case!!)

-boot from a CD (like a ubuntu/fedora liveCD, a gparted liveCD, hirensCD, etc) and start the gparted from the CD, so you dont have anything mounted on the HD.

-Then move the NTFS, then the EXTENDED (all of it), then expand the EXTENDED partition and finally expand the sda5

also, why don't you merge the 2 swap partitions, i dont see the need for 2 sequential but different swap partitions

Comment: When I attempt to move the OS ntfs partition gParted gives me a warning about, how the OS on the partition may no longer boot.

Comment: @Ayos - true, the sectors used by NTLDR will probably be moved and so the boot sectors is pointing to the wrong place. moving the boot partitions in all OS is always a tricky thing, you may need to rebuild the boot sectors. In windows you need to boot from the recover CD and do a fix-boot and in linux rerun the grub-install or lilo